# Почему не работает скрипт на смену градуса градиента?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        window.onload = asd ;
            function asd (){
                setInterval(e, 900);

            }
            function e () {
                document.getElementById(body).style.background-image = "linear-gradient(" + a + "deg , #D4145A , #FBB03B)"

            }
            var a = 45;
            function f(){
  a=a+20;
};
setInterval(f, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">



    <style type="text/css">

        #body {
            background-image: linear-gradient(45deg , #D4145A , #FBB03B);
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage` или `document.body.style.backgroundImage`

Comment: Спасибо, но появился трабл в том, что он начал менять лишь справа налево и наоборот :D

Answer (score 0):

> он начал менять лишь справа налево и наоборот

У Вас градиент повторяется по вертикали в узких горизонтальных полосках, поэтому кажется, что он рисуется только в горизонтальном направлении.

```js
window.onload = asd;

function asd() {
  setInterval(e, 200);
}

var a = 45;
function e() {
  a = a + 5;
  document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(" + a + "deg , yellow, red) fixed";
}
```